# can we control the zoom speed while we do pinch zoom in android google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, pinchzoom

Is there any way increase the zoom sensitivity in android google map?

I just found some difference between the app i have developed and the ola app. ola can zoom to street level faster from the world view. But i am not sure its happening with zoom levels while zoom..

I have map in full screen as i have removed action bar and status bar, but ola keeps action bar, so map is little smaller than mine, this may be also a reason..

Just want to know whether we can control the zoom speed while we do pinch zoom..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I may be off base, but I think the actual speed of pinch zoom is just how fast your fingers move.  How quickly the app/widget/etc. _responds_ to this depends on the app.  What would be your ideal behavior here?

Comment: Okay... I just want to speedup the zoom level... instead of 8 full pinch zooms  to go to street level i want to do it only with 5 full zooms. Any hack?

Comment: Good question +1 ... I added this one to my favorites as I use Google Maps with Android pretty heavily.